# Population growth at a certain time

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

i have this differential equation:

$$x' = 2.5(45-x(t)) $$ And the initial condition $x(0)=8$, if now i want to know the growth at $t=6$ i proceed like this:

$$ \int \frac{dx}{45-x}=\int 2.5dt \implies x = 45\pm e^c e^{2.5t}$$

So if i had that $x(0)=8$ then i have that if $C_1 = \pm e^c$ then $C_1 = -37$

So i have the solution $ x = 45 - 37e^{2.5t}$, now trying to get $t=6$, the number i get is really strange and it says me i am doing something wrong given that the equation was for calculating growths of fishes.

Comment: Replace every $e^{2.5t}$ by $e^{-2.5t}$.

Comment: Try to solve more carefully the differential equation and you should see why.

Comment: Sorry i did it again and i keep getting a positive value, unless $\pm e^c $ has something to do?

Comment: Which primitive of 1/(45-x) are you using?

Comment: Ok, i have $-ln|45-x|$ and therefore it should  be $e^{-2.5t}$, i was doing it with $ln|45-x|$. Sorry i am not very skillfull at this yet.

Comment: @user137201 Don't be sorry! It's a good thing to hit an error like that. It'll only make you more vigilant in the future.

Comment: You might want to write an answer explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

I was integrating wrong and forgeting a sign on the exponent

$$ \int \frac{dx}{45-x}=\int 2.5dt \implies -ln|45-x| = 2.5t + c\implies x = 45\pm e^c e^{-2.5t}$$

So now the result for $x$ it is coherent.